# Ruby - Update jsonb array column setup with jsonb_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I have this field called `data` that was setup with the `jsonb_accessor` ruby gem like this:

```
jsonb_accessor :data,
  line_items: [:jsonb, array: true, default: []]
```

This is on my `Contract` model. And when a `Contract` is created, its an empty array like this:

```
data: {"line_items"=>[]},
```

I want to add multiple hashes to this empty array. For example this:

```
{user: "Joe"}
```

Then later I may add the hash:

```
{user: "Jack"}
```

I've tried many things, with NO luck including:

```
new = [{user: "Joe"}].to_json
Contract.last.update_all(["line_items = line_items || ?::jsonb", new])
##
Contract.last.update(["line_items = line_items || ?::jsonb", new])
```

Then I tried `push`

```
Contract.last.line_items.push("line_items" => {user: "Todd"})
```

Then I tried `merge`

```
Contract.last.line_items = Contract.last.line_items.merge(new)
```

Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

One option would just be to set the attribute with the data you want, then persist it with `#save` (or `#save!`)

```
contract = Contract.create!
=> #<Contract id: 1, data: {"line_items"=>[]}, line_items: []>

contract.line_items = [{foo: "bar"}]
contract.save!

contract
=> #<Contract id: 1, data: {"line_items"=>[{"foo"=>"bar"}]}, line_items: [{"foo"=>"bar"}]>
```

In my testing, I was able to use the #update method by just passing the object itself (rather than converting it to JSON first):

```
Contract.update(1, :line_items => [{foo: "bar"}])
=> #<Contract id: 1, data: {"line_items"=>[{"foo"=>"bar"}]}, line_items: [{"foo"=>"bar"}]>
```

**Edit:**
It looks like you're trying to append to the array with a single query, which appears to be possible with

```
Contract.where(id: 1).update_all("data=jsonb_set(data,'{line_items}', data->'line_items' || '{\"foo\": \"bar\"}')")
```

Though I'm sure there is a better way to achieve the same functionality...

Answer (score 0):

jsonb_accessor means you *don't* have to manually mess around with JSON for simple accessor operations. If you want to assign to `line_items` use `update!` like normal.

```
contract.update!(line_items: [{user: "Joe"}])
```

If you want to append to a single Contract's `line_items`, add to the array in Ruby and update.

```
contract = Contract.last
line_items = contract.line_items + [{user: "Joe"}]
contract.update!(line_items: line_items)
```

If you want to do it all in SQL `jsonb_accessor` offers you no help. You have to write the SQL yourself. To add to an array, use [`jsonb_insert`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING).

```
Contract
  .where(...)
  .update_all(
    q[jsonb_insert(data, '{"line_items", -1}', '{user: "Joe"}', true)]
  )
```

`'{"line_items", -1}'` says to insert at the last element of the key "line_items" and `true` has to insert after that point.